# Convert const char* to binary operator+

Tags: c, string, arduino, concatenation

I'm stuck at trying to figure out the correct data types for `T1` and `P1` (see below).

Compiler error:

```
weather_station_v1_2.ino:76:37: error: invalid operands of types ‘const char*’ and ‘const char [11]’ to binary ‘operator+’
```

The Code:

```
if (status != 0) {
      delay(status);
      status = pressure.getPressure(P,T);

      const unsigned char P1 = pressure.getTemperature(P);
      const unsigned char T1 = pressure.getTemperature(T);

      byte data = "temp" + T1 + "&pressure=" + P1;
      httppost();
      delay(1000);
    }
```

At the end `data` will be send to a PHP server, but it has to follow the scheme `name1=value1&name2=value2`.

Would you be so nice and give me a hint about what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: are you in need of `snprintf()`?

Comment: yes, it seems so xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not one of data type conversion, but that in C the operator `+` is defined only for arithmetic operations (adding numbers, or adding an offset to a pointer).

You're attempting to concatenate strings. There is no "string" type built into C. C "strings" are char arrays, usually terminated with a 0 byte. Arrays in C are fixed size and fixed allocation so there is no array "concatenation" operator in C.

Operations on arrays, and thereby also on C "strings", are usually implemented through manipulation functions. In your particular case the usual approach is the use of a string formatting function of the `printf` family. You should look at `snprintf`.

Comment: Nice "hint" answer per OP request.  UV (Quibble: Disagree with ""strings ... usually terminated with a 0 byte".  In C, _strings always_ end with a null character, else it is not a string.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, my code does work now :)
`if (status != 0) {
          delay(status);
          status = pressure.getPressure(P,T);
          
          const unsigned char P1 = pressure.getTemperature(P);
          const unsigned char T1 = pressure.getTemperature(T);

          char buffer [100];
          byte data = snprintf(buffer, 100, "temp=%T1&pressure=%P1", T1, P1);
          
          httppost();
          delay(1000);
        }`

Comment: @hehxes  `"temp=%T1&pressure=%P1"` is an unusual format.  Sure it works?

Comment: @chux: Yes, the C standard defines that const string literals that are not initializers always terminate with a 0 byte. However this `char hello[5] = "hello";` is perfectly legal, but will not terminate with a 0 byte. As far as the standard library `str…` functions is concerned this is not a string of course. The borders of what a string is and what not are a bit blurry. IMHO the use of the in-band signalling 0 byte terminator was one of the worse decisions in the C design process. Sure, having to drag around the length explicitly is annoying, but it would have prevented so many security bugs.

Comment: `"hello"` is a _string  literal_, not necessarily a _string_.  True C has blurry terminology.

Comment: Disagree with "in-band signaling 0" problem.  Pascal, came out not much later than C.  It used a string length.  Possible other languages used a string length.  C survived - they did not.  (Beta is better than VHS - but it died).  Had C used the "better" explicit length, we might be complaining about `D` today  and not the forgotten C.  The null character solution worked well for the time.  Yes it is cumbersome today.  I hope for a standard C UTF8 string solution with a explicit use length and buffer size.

Comment: @chux: I think the reasons for Pascal's demise were not the way it managed strings. The main reasons would have been that there was only a single compiler of significance (Borland) and that the way in which libraries had to be packaged and distributed was kind of cumbersome. Add to that that modifying the underlying runtime system was impractical and which made it a poor fit for OS kernel development. Most runlevel low level stuff was hand written in assembly targeting the BIOS or the OS syscalls.

Comment: @chux: that was kind of a blast from the past. Pascal was the first high level language I learnt and wrote quite a number of programs with (IIRC the first substancially complex program was a control system for my model railroad).

Comment: @datenwolf I miss Borland turbo Pascal BCD floating point option.  It was not a single attribute that determines a products success, but the net of the various features - some good, some not-so-good.  OTOH anymore of a Turbo P love-fest and we'll need a room.